# Permanently disable AutoEventWireup

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on a project where performance is really important and i would like to disable AutoEventWireup permanently. The problem is in the fact that the page and control directives override the settings from web.config. Since there will be many collaborators on this project it will be impossible to expect everyone to disable it when creating new pages and controls (and it is true by default). **Is it possible to somehow enforce this rule?**

I hoped to solve this in a similar way as I did with the ViewState - setting the EnableViewState to false programmatically in the base page that all new pages inherit. But it seems there is no equivalent for AutoEventWireup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override **[SupportAutoEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.supportautoevents%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public BasePage()
    {
        this.Init += (_o, _e) => {
            this.Load += (o, e) => {
                Response.Write("in page handler");
            };
        };
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this handler is NOT assigned to the Load event
        Response.Write("assigned by ASP .Net handler");            
    }
    protected sealed override bool SupportAutoEvents
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the documentation: "This property supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code." Can you explanation of what you're doing? :)

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thanx

Comment: So what exactly did you figure out to get this resolved? If I did not understand incorrectly, you need to set the autoeventwireup to false for future pages..Right?

Comment: There is no AutoEventWireUp property in the Page class, but the parser which helps at the page compilation, reads this value and uses it on another method, HookUpAutomaticHandlers. This method checks if SupportAutoEvents is true and if so then does that search for the handlers. See this resource http://ale.riolo.co.uk/2007/09/autoeventwireup-is-evil.html

Answer (score 0):

Create your own set of controls for each of the out of the box ones that you want to disable these properties for. Then set the two controls in the inherited versions to readonly.